# Riddick and the Space Police

Tags: mathematics, geometry, pursuit-evasion

The next problem may be way too easy, but will post it anyway.

> Riddick, trying to escape from the space police, lands on a deserted
>   planet. How many cops should the space police send to the planet, so
>   that Riddick will be eventually caught?
>
> We assume that the planet is a perfect sphere and the speed of Riddick
>   and all cops is the same. All of the characters have perfect
>   information about the location of the others and make instant
>   decisions in real-time. Also, they are dots.

P.S. The question seems very natural, I hope it is not a repeat.

Comment: Yeah, it is the same, please erase the question or mark it as duplicate - whichever is better. Sorry for the repeat.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the hare-wolves one. In that question, the creatures have a small but nonzero radius (see second comment). In this one, the players are points. This changes the answer: in the other question, two pursuers can catch the evader, in this one, two pursuers cannot catch the evader.

Comment: That's true, but the first solution there gives the strategy for 2 cops. I posted the problem mostly because of my strategy for 3 cops, but I guess will try to make up some twist and come up with a modified problem.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the space police want to send as few units as possible

> they should send three (3) units

This is because

> This is a standard [pursuit game](http://www.opengrey.eu/item/display/10068/350787) on $S^2$. Riddick can evade any two pursuers indefinitely (for example, by moving in a direction perpendicular to the great circle containing the locations of the pursuers as they approach him), but three pursuers can inevitably trap him in a kind of "collapsing triangle", as well as with other strategies.
> Of course, he'll probably just kick their arses to Hades and back, but...

Comment: 3 is correct. However, I am not totally convinced with the "shrinking triangle" part. Since they are on a sphere, there are two triangles defined by any 3 points - which one do you shrink?

Comment: The one with Riddick in it, I'd assume